# PERCENT DIFFERENCE FROM calculation

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau if you do a "PERCENT DIFFERNCE FROM" calculation there is a sign issue

the typical % diff calculation is (EndingValue - Beginning Value)/Beginning Value so if you have negative numbers like

```
 (-41- (-40))/-40  = 2.5%
```

but in Tableau you will see -2.5%. Why is that? Can it be changed?

Comment: you can choose `edit in shelf` option from the field context menu . copy the entire thing and paste into a new field where you can change sign as you wish as calculation to happen .

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the calculation into `abs`

I,e take out the `absolute value` of the calculation

<kbd>[More Info.](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/functions_functions_number.html)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking to remove the negative sign of the number then you need to use absolute value. The absolute value of any number is never negative.

Here are a few examples:

```
ABS(-7) = 7

ABS(10 - 20) = 10

ABS((-41-(-40))/-40) = 2.5%
```